# Existence of morphisms between diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

First of all, as they say, first time-long time. I made an effort to find any duplicate or relevant questions but my vocabulary was limited and so was my success. Hopefully I can articulate myself clearly enough to communicate my meaning.

I have a fairly basic question about category theory. I'm working through chapter 1 of Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 and while I can more or less make sense of most of the material, there's one thing in particular that's really wrinkling my brain.

Aluffi makes use of some categories as examples (specifically of note here: $C^A$, $C^{A,B}$ et al). In particular, he asserts that the morphisms between objects in these diagrams are themselves commutative diagrams, which sort of makes sense (still working on it). [Here's a snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2AIu.png)

**My specific question is**: how can we be certain of the existence of these morphisms $\sigma$ (morphisms in $C$, I guess) that can have the same image (am I thinking too much in terms of set-functions here?)? In other words, I think I'm having trouble understanding how we can be so certain of the commutativity of the diagrams above.

Please let me know if I can clarify the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For given $A$ and $B$ there may or may not be any diagrams like the one at the top of the page. If there are the category $C_{A,B}$ is nonempty
and these diagrams are the objects. Given two such diagrams with $Z_1$
and $Z_2$ there may or may not exist $\sigma$ making the final diagram
commute. In any case the $\sigma$ that make the diagram commute are the
morphisms in $C_{A,B}$ between the two diagrams. (There may be no such $\sigma$).

A good exercise is to prove that the composition of two morphisms
of $C_{A,B}$ is also a morphism of $C_{A,B}$.

Comment: To put it more compactly, the morphisms of $C_{A,B}$ are simply *by definition* such commutative diagrams. A diagram of that form that does not commute is simply not an example of a morphism of $C_{A,B}$.